# Naming convention for function that loops N times

Tags: loops, iteration, naming-conventions

Is there an established naming convention for functions that receive an integer *n* and do an action *n* times?

For example:

```
function foo(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i > n; i++)
    console.log(n);
}
```

How would you name `foo` in a way that would be obvious from its name that it loops for a set amount of times? I've seen "`many`" used for this purpose, i.e. `printMany(5)`, but I don't know how widely accepted that is.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there's an established convention, I would be surprised to find out that there is; it's not a thing used that much in real programs.

One name more descriptive than `printMany` might be `printNTimes`, that is a little awkward to read though. If you are not compelled to use camelCase `print_n_times` seems better.

---

An alternative, if your language supports named parameters, is to call the parameter `times` and strive to call the function like this: `print(times:5)`.

Of course this usage can't be enforced (in all languages that I know the named parameters can also be accessed positionally), but just putting a comment over the function definition recommending this practice would probably be enough to make every caring programmer use it. And if someone doesn't you can blame him for writing unclear code.